# Wooded Kingdom - Moons over the ? in the corner of the map

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

When asking for hints in the Wooded Kingdom, it gives me about 8 moons in the bottom right of the map, over the ? symbol.

[image]

Where the hell is this location, and how do I access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can jump off the top of the barrier/wall in the south east corner, right near the Odyssey, and reach the Deep Woods area.  There are numerous power moons to obtain down there in addition to some surprises, and some plants that will allow you to get back up.

The clue that tells you about this doesn't seem to appear until you've beaten the game, after which one of the robots will appear there and inform you there's an area over the wall.

Comment: You can also learn about this area by falling off the the level by accident like an idiot

Comment: This is also referenced by the second tourist location on the right side of the pamphlet - “A Deep Wood’s Secret.”